# Permission error with Docker-compose and MYSQL

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have been trying to dockerize both a MySQL database and a Go REST server together. This exact configuration has worked for me in the past, and is no longer working. Cannot find a solution anywhere.

```
   version: '3'
    services:
     db:
        image: mysql 
        restart: always
        expose:
          - 3306
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=puapp
        volumes:
          - db_volume:/var/lib/mysql
          - ./mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
      api-service:
        build: ../.. 
        restart: always
        ports:
          - "80:8080"
        expose:
          - 8080
        environment:
          - DB_USER=root
          - DB_PASS=root
          - DB_ADDRESS=db:3306
          - DB_PROTOCOL=tcp
          - DB_NAME=puapp
        depends_on:
          - db
        links:
          - db
    
    volumes:
      db_volume:
```

Error:

```
feature-db-1           | 2021-11-22 22:39:27+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql
feature-db-1           | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 75: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your container cannot read the file dump.sql in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ which mount to the directory on your host ./mysql. `chmod 777 ./mysql` to allow the read.